# Validation Rule Help - Require Checkbox before Advancing to Stage

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I have a checkbox called 'Company_Address_Complete__c', that I want to ensure is checked before someone can advance to Won, Lost or Project closed. Can someone tell me why this is failing with this error: "Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISBLANK()'."

```
AND (
  OR (
     ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Opportunity Won"),
     ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Opportunity Lost"),
     ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Project Closed")),   
     ISBLANK(  Company_Address_Complete__c  )
)
```

Comment: FYI you can format your code by hitting the `{}` button in your editor, or selecting the block and hitting `CTRL+K`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to throw an error when the checkbox is unchecked, you would do:

```
NOT(My_Checkbox__c)
```

So your formula should look like:

```
AND(
    NOT(Company_Address_Complete__c),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, ...),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, ...),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, ...)
    )
)
```

Note it's more efficient to switch your `OR` statement to a `CASE`:

```
AND(
    NOT(...),
    1 = CASE(
        TEXT(StageName),
        "Opportunity Won", 1,
        "Opportunity Lost", 1,
        "Project Closed", 1,
        0
    )
)
```